# Confusing Arduino Leonardo PWM

Tags: arduino-yun, arduino-leonardo, pwm, atmega32u4

I'm having problems with using Arduino Leonardo PWM outputs (I'm actually using YUN board).

I need 4 PWM outputs that generally have the same base frequency of around 10 to 20 Hz or so.

I'm using timer 1 (A-pin-9,B-pin-10,C-pin-11) and timer 4 (A-pin-13)

I get pins 9,10,and 13 PWM output working decent, but for some reason pin 11 PWM frequency is much much higher.

Pins 9,10,11 should be working off TIMER 1 which all use the same pre-scaler, so I dont know how 9 and 10 can have one frequency, and 11 have a different frequency.

Here is my code can anybody see anything wrong? thanks!

```
    #define PWM_4A_PIN  13 
    #define PWM_1C_PIN  11

    #define PWM_1B_PIN  10 
    #define PWM_1A_PIN  9 

    void setup() {
     TCCR1B = TCCR1B & 0b11111000 | 0x05;
     TCCR4B = TCCR1B & 0b11110000 | 0x09;
     analogWrite(PWM_4A_PIN,128);
     analogWrite(PWM_1C_PIN,128);
     analogWrite(PWM_1B_PIN,128);
     analogWrite(PWM_1A_PIN,128);
    }

    void loop() 
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Pins 9,10,11 should be working off TIMER 1 which all use the same pre-scaler, so I dont know how 9 and 10 can have one frequency, and 11 have a different frequency.

Unless D11 is configured as OC0A instead of OC1C, which means that it will work off timer 0.

```
TCCR0A &= ~(_BV(COM0A1) | _BV(COM0A0));
TCCR1A |= _BV(COM1C1) | _BV(COM1C0);
 ...
OCR1C = ...;
```

Comment: Thanks Inacio, I tried your code but the same result D11 has much higher freq than 9 and 10, its very strange!

Comment: Did you use `analogWrite()` on D11? That will reset it to OC0A.

Comment: if I replace analogWrite(11,128) with OCR1C=128, then no output at all

Comment: Here is the whole code as it is now#define PWM_4A_PIN  13 
#define PWM_1C_PIN  11

#define PWM_1B_PIN  10 
#define PWM_1A_PIN  9 

void setup() {
 TCCR1B = TCCR1B & 0b11111000 | 0x05;
 TCCR4B = TCCR1B & 0b11110000 | 0x09;
 
 TCCR0A &= ~(_BV(COM0A1) | _BV(COM0A0));
 TCCR3A |= _BV(COM1C1) | _BV(COM1C0);
 
 //TCCR0A=0;
 //TCCR1A=0xb01010101;
 pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
 OCR1C=128;
 analogWrite(PWM_4A_PIN,128);
 //analogWrite(PWM_1C_PIN,128);
 analogWrite(PWM_1B_PIN,128);
 analogWrite(PWM_1A_PIN,128); 
}

void loop() {

}

Comment: Call `analogWrite()` once to configure everything else, then perform the assignments in my answer.

Comment: void setup() {
 TCCR1B = TCCR1B & 0b11111000 | 0x05;
 TCCR4B = TCCR1B & 0b11110000 | 0x09;
 
 analogWrite(PWM_4A_PIN,128);
 analogWrite(PWM_1C_PIN,128);
 analogWrite(PWM_1B_PIN,128);
 analogWrite(PWM_1A_PIN,128); 
 
 TCCR0A &= ~(_BV(COM0A1) | _BV(COM0A0));
 TCCR3A |= _BV(COM1C1) | _BV(COM1C0);
 
 //TCCR0A=0;
 //TCCR1A=0xb01010101;
 OCR1C=128;
}  D11 as no output anymore, but 9,10,and 13 still works

Comment: WORKS NOW!!! you have typo in your answer, TCCR3A should be TCCR1A, I changed that one thing and now it works!! THANKS VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP GOD BLESS YOU!!!

Comment: Pfft, yes, I suppose I goofed that part. Stupid joint datasheet sections...

Comment: why when I write to analogWrite it makes it back to OCOA???

Comment: I need to keep changing the PWM duty cycle, so I cant use analogwrite for any pin, only OC1C, OC1A, OC1B fro then on?

Comment: `analogWrite()` does a lot of housekeeping behind the scenes, including preparing the pin for how *it* thinks it should work. One of these bits is setting D11 as OC0A. Another is setting the PWM frequency. Sometimes the Arduino libraries are handy, and sometimes they interfere.